# Solving exponential equation $\frac{3^x+2^x}{3^x-2^x}=7$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, exponentiation

I'm currently working on a math problem that involves solving an exponential equation with fractions. Here's the equation:

$$
\frac{3^x+2^x}{3^x-2^x}=7
$$

I've been trying to solve it on my own, but I'm stuck and would really appreciate some help. My attempt at solving the problem involved multiplying both sides by the denominator, which gave me:

$$
3^x+2^x=7(3^x-2^x)
$$

Expanding the right-hand side, I got:

$$
3^x+2^x=7\cdot 3^x-7\cdot 2^x
$$

Then I moved all the terms involving $3^x$ to the left-hand side and all the terms involving $2^x$ to the right-hand side, which gave me:

$$
9\cdot 2^x=6\cdot 3^x
$$

Dividing both sides by $2^x\cdot 3^x$, I got:

$$
\frac{9}{6}=\left(\frac{3}{2}\right)^x
$$

Simplifying, I got:

$$
\left(\frac{3}{2}\right)^x=\frac{3}{2}
$$

And that's where I got stuck. I'm not sure how to proceed from here to find the largest solution to the equation. Can anyone give me a hint or point me in the right direction?

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: It should be $8\cdot2^x=6\cdot 3^x$.

Comment: Your last statement $$
\left(\frac{3}{2}\right)^x=\frac{3}{2}
$$ is not true. Take $x=1$ in the original equation.

Comment: You will end up with $(3/2)^x=4/3$, then take logs.

Comment: @DietrichBurde My approach was this but I'm not sure if I made the right steps. $$\frac{4}{3} =\left( \frac{3}{2} \right)^{x}  \Leftrightarrow \ln \frac{4}{3} =\ln \frac{3^{x}}{2^{x}} \Leftrightarrow x=\frac{\ln \frac{4}{3} }{\ln \frac{3}{2} } \Leftrightarrow x=\frac{\ln 4-\ln 3}{\ln 3-\ln 2}$$ The answer says it should be $$x=\frac{2\ln 2-\ln 3}{\ln 3-\ln 2}$$

Comment: Dani, this is correct because $4=2^2$, so $\log(4)=\log(2^2)=2\log(2)$.

Comment: @Dani You could also edit your question indicating the correction and teh final result.

Answer (score 2):

Your work is fine, as noticed you have made a mistake here

$$3^x+2^x=7\cdot 3^x-7\cdot 2^x \implies 8\cdot 2^x=6\cdot 3^x \implies \left(\frac{3}{2}\right)^x=\frac{4}{3}$$

from which we can easily conclude using logarithm.

As an alternative manipulation, using that

$$\frac{3^x+2^x}{3^x-2^x}=7 \iff \frac{\left(\frac{3}{2}\right)^x+1}{\left(\frac{3}{2}\right)^x-1}=7$$

and by $y=\left(\frac{3}{2}\right)^x-1$ we obtain

$$\frac{y+2}{y}=1+\frac2y=7 \implies y=\frac13 \implies \left(\frac{3}{2}\right)^x=\frac{4}{3}$$

Comment: My approach was this but I'm not sure if I made the right steps. $$\frac{4}{3} =\left( \frac{3}{2} \right)^{x}  \Leftrightarrow \ln \frac{4}{3} =\ln \frac{3^{x}}{2^{x}} \Leftrightarrow x=\frac{\ln \frac{4}{3} }{\ln \frac{3}{2} } \Leftrightarrow x=\frac{\ln 4-\ln 3}{\ln 3-\ln 2}$$ The answer says it should be $$x=\frac{2\ln 2-\ln 3}{\ln 3-\ln 2}$$

Comment: @Dani Yes we simply have $$\left(\frac{3}{2}\right)^x=\frac{4}{3} \iff x\log \frac32 =\log \frac43 \iff x= \frac{\log \frac43}{\log \frac32}$$ which is also equivalent to $$x=\frac{2\ln 2-\ln 3}{\ln 3-\ln 2}$$ but we don't need necessarly this further step.

Comment: More in general, for any $A>0$ we have $$A^x=B \iff x\log A=\log B \iff x=\frac{\log B}{\log A}$$